# How to capture the row hover event in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I was going through the documentation of `ag-grid` and looks like there is no event to capture the row hover event for the grid. My requirement is to display the image on the first column when the user hovers on the row. It might be on any column of the row, not necessarily the first cell. I'm using a cell-renderer and cell-editor and performing certain actions. (For simplicity, I didn't post the cell editor code in the plunker link) How can I achieve this?

Please see the plunkr example: https://plnkr.co/edit/NfuGp3iVheuCqglz

`app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import {KaboobMenuComponent} from './kaboob-menu.component';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
       [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
    
  private columnDefs;
  private defaultColDef;
  private rowData: [];
  public frameworkComponents;
    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Participant',
        children: [
          {
        headerName: '',
        filter: false,
        sortable: false,
        editable: true,
        singleClickEdit: true,
        cellRenderer: 'kaboobRenderer',        
      },
      { field: 'athlete' },
          {
            field: 'age',
            maxWidth: 90,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Details',
        children: [
          { field: 'country' },
          {
            field: 'year',
            maxWidth: 90,
          },
          { field: 'date' },
          { field: 'sport' },
        ],
      }     
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 150,
      resizable: true,
    };
    this.frameworkComponents = {
      kaboobRenderer: KaboobMenuComponent
    };
  }
    
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http
      .get(
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinners.json'
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
      });
  }
}
```

`kaboob-menu.component.ts` (My Custom Renderer):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-kaboob-menu',
  template: `<img border="0" width="15" height="10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/images/smiley.png"/>`,  
})

export class KaboobMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  params: any;
  rowData: any;
  display = true;
    
  constructor() { }
    
  agInit(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.rowData = params.data;    
  }
   
  ngOnInit() {
  }
    
  onClick($event) {
    if (this.params.onClick instanceof Function) {
      const params = {
        event: $event,
        rowData: this.params.node.data
      };
      this.params.onClick(params);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the `cellMouseOver` event, but this event is fired when we hover on the first column and not on any other columns. I want to capture the row hover event.

Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I also have similar requirement. I have used CSS styling and `ag-grid` class names to show the content of cell on row hover:

- Initially hide the content of the cell by styling (`display: none` for that cell)
- On row hover, ag-grid adds `ag-row-hover` CSS class, use this class selector to show the content of the cell.

Lets imagine your image class is `my-image`, so you have to define the styling as below:

```css
.my-image {
  display: none;
}

/* ag-grid adds ag-row-hover class on row hover */
.ag-row-hover .my-image {
  display: initial;
}
```

For your example, you should define these styles in your `kaboob-menu.component.ts` ("My Custom Renderer")

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/78THewIj4jUIUUVd)

Answer (score 1):

I would listen to `cellMouseOver` event emitted by the grid.

In your html: `(cellMouseOver)="onCellMouseOver($event)"`

In your component:

```js
onCellMouseOver(params) {
  console.log(params.rowIndex); // 0
}
```

The params object has a `rowIndex` to identify which row it is on regardless of the cell. You can manipulate your rowNode inside this `onCellMouseOver`

Comment: I should have been more specific. I'm currently doing cellMouseOver, but it would work for hovering on the cell. I want to capture the hover on the row to manipulate whether to display or hide the first column in that row. I'll edit the post

Comment: onCellMouseOver is triggered for all cells and not just the first cell. The params object has access to the rowIndex as well as the node which should help you blank out your data for the column you want to hide

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the rowNode data from params. But, how to I show/ hide the image in the first column? Which property should I look into? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: once you know which row the mouse is on, you can basically set some value on params.data.hoverOn = true and then  do api.refreshCells() to re trigger your cell renderer? your cell renderer can have some logic to show/hide based on this hoverOn property